# Case insensitive omniauth-identity email login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

By default the intridea / omniauth-identity rails gem uses email to login and they are case sensitive. How do I make the login email *case insensitive*? Adding ":case_sensitive => false" to the model as seen below does not work.

```
#models/identity.rb
class Identity < OmniAuth::Identity::Models::ActiveRecord
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :case_sensitive => false
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i
end
```

For example, even with the model above if you signed up with "bob@aol.com" and then tried to login with "BOB@aol.com" the login would produce an OMNIAUTH::ERROR of invalid credentials.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I thought user ForgetTheNorm had the solution, but it turns out modifying the locate_conditions breaks sign up. The solution is actually much simpler than I originally thought. Downcase the auth-key BEFORE it is submitted with the form.  This is true of everywhere you use the key. For instance, to login or sign up.

```
  #login-form
  <%= form_tag('/auth/identity/callback', :method => 'post', :id => 'actual-login-form') do %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= label_tag :auth_key, 'Email' %>
      <br />
      <%= text_field_tag :auth_key, nil, :class => 'user-auth-field user-auth-key' %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= label_tag :password %>
      <br />
      <%= password_field_tag :password, nil, :class => 'user-auth-field' %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= submit_tag 'Sign in', :class => 'btn-default', :id => 'modal-sign-in' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

 #signup-form
  <%= form_tag('/auth/identity/register', :method => 'post', :id => 'actual-signup-form') do %>
    <%= label_tag(nil, 'Choose your username') %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'name', nil, :class => 'signup-form-input', :tabindex => '1' %>

    <%= label_tag(:email, 'Your current email address') %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'email', nil, :class => 'signup-form-input user-auth-key', :tabindex => '2' %>

    <%= label_tag(:password, 'Create a password') %>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="signup-form-input" tabindex="3" />

    <%= label_tag(:password2, 'Confirm your password') %>
    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" class="signup-form-input" tabindex="4" />

    <%= submit_tag('Sign Up for Pholder', :id => 'signup-submit', :tabindex => '5') %>
  <% end %>
```

Relevant jQuery/JS:

```
 $('#actual-login-form, #actual-signup-form').on('submit', function(){

   //lower case auth key (email addresses) for all user validation
 $(this).find('.user-auth-key').val( $(this).find('.user-auth-key').val().toLowerCase()  )

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find solutions in

https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-identity/issues/22

> For the sake of clarity...
>
> ```
> #config/initializers/omniauth.rb
> provider :identity, locate_conditions: lambda { |req| 
>    { model.auth_key => req['auth_key'].downcase }
> }
> ```
>
> As ujeezy noted above, the omniauth-identity gem on Rubygems does not
>   support this feature, this is still true. Make sure your gemfile is as
>   he stated:
>
> ```
> #Gemfile
> gem 'omniauth-identity', git: 'https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-identity.git'
> ```

Comment: This throws an error on identity creation, fyi. Not a stable solution.

Comment: @ericpeters0n More information than "throws an error" should be appreciable. Works fine for me.

Comment: NoMethodError at /auth/identity/callback
undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass

(Upon submission of new identity, Fyi @ForgetTheNorm )

Comment: tTo prevent the nil error, you can just use this 
lambda { |req| { model.auth_key => (req['auth_key'].present? ? req['auth_key'].downcase : req['auth_key']) } }